# How to monitor DUT outputs from a test/sequence?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, uvm

I am a beginner in UVM. So far I was able to create the following environment for my DUT.

Agents with monitors, drivers and sequences for all of the input-output interfaces from my DUT.
A top level UVM env. 
Sequences to send valid data to DUT. I yet to implement scoreboard.

I'm having some trouble to understand how to handle scenarios like following:

For a tb-dut interface, TB needs to wait for an event (or transaction) from DUT. Once it receives the transaction, TB needs to send back a response. What is the best way to implement this? How can I monitor DUT transaction from sequence? My agents have monitors which will monitor any new output signals from DUT. So, do I need to somehow bring this data from agent's monitor to my test/sequence class? I know that monitor has an analysis port and it can be used to send received data to scoreboard for checking. So, do I need to use the same port to read DUT output data, create valid response and send it to DUT?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

This is know as a slave sequence or responder. The protocol is as follows

1. Slave sequence sends a request to the driver - "Tell me what to do"
2. Driver detects a bus level request and returns the information back to the sequence - "This is what you should do"
3. Slave sequence does what it needs to do to prepare a response and then sends a response item to the driver - "Here you go"
4. Driver completes the bus level response with the contents of the response item, completes handshake back to the sequence - "Thank
   you"

This is explained in more detail in the Verification Academy [UVM Cookbook](https://verificationacademy.com/cookbook/sequences/slave).

Comment: Thanks a lot dave. I'm working on a response sequence. I think I was able to made some progress in getting request data from DUT to a response agent. Do you mind having a look at my latest question regarding this? I'm totally new to uvm land. I would greatly appreciate any input/pointers...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024817/failing-to-write-in-systemverilog-mailbox

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using uvm_object.

1. Create uvm_object base class. Define your virtual method, for example wait_state, but leave it empty.
2. Extend that class and implement the virtual method. Include the class inside the testbench and instantiate an object. Say the object is "my_tb"
3. Use uvm_config_db#(uvm_object)::set ... to pass it to sequencer
4. Grab the object inside the sequencer usign uvm_config_db#(uvm_object)::get ...
5. From inside your sequence: any where any time you can access it: p_sequencer.my_tb.wait_state().